# Sort alphanumeric in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I need help to order the next statement:

```
select numbering from QuestionnaireQuestion where  
QuestionnaireQuestion.questionnaire_id = 20 AND 
    QuestionnaireQuestion.numbering is not null
    order by LEFT(numbering,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',numbering)-1)
```

the result is:

Q2
Q2.a
Q2.b
Q3
Q4
Q4.a
Q5
Q6
Q6.a
Q6.a.1
Q6.a.2
Q6.a.3
Q6.a.4
Q7
Q8
Q8.a
Q9
Q10
Q10.a
Q10.b
Q11
Q11.a
Q12
Q12.a
Q12.b
Q13
Q13.a
Q13.a.1
Q13.a.2
Q13.a.3
Q13.a.4
Q13.a.5
Q13.a.6
Q13.a.7
Q13.a.8
Q13.b
Q13.b.1
Q13.b.2
Q13.b.3
Q13.b.4
Q13.b.5
Q13.b.6
Q13.b.7
Q13.b.8
**Q1**

The last is Q1, but i need to Q1 in the TOP

Comment: Can you guarantee that the numbering never goes into double-digits (e.g., `Q10`)?

Comment: What happens with order by 'numbering'?

Comment: @Mureinik: They may also contain 2 or more digits (e.g.. Q13 or Q13.a or Q13.a.1)

Comment: @Grantly the result is:                                                                             Q1                  
Q10                 
Q10.a               
Q10.b               
Q11                 
Q11.a               
Q12                 
Q12.a               
Q12.b               
Q13                 
Q13.a               
Q13.a.1             
Q13.a.2             
Q13.a.3             
Q13.a.4             
Q13.a.5             
Q13.a.6             
Q13.a.7             
Q13.a.8

Comment: This is why you should not store more than 1 piece of a data in a single tuple. If this was normalized it would be painless to sort this.

Comment: Just order by Numbering column: order by numbering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need the substring, not the left

```
order by substring(numbering,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',numbering),100)
```

however this will not solve for 10 and above, but the following will:

```
select numbering , right('0000'+substring(numbering,pos1,pos2-pos1),4)
from QuestionnaireQuestion 
cross apply (
      select PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',rtrim(numbering)), PATINDEX('%[.]%',rtrim(numbering)+'.')
   ) ca (pos1, pos2)
order by right('0000'+substring(numbering,pos1,pos2-pos1),4), numbering
```

It "left pads" the first number found e.g. 6 becomes 0006 or 91 become 0091 and so on.

The cross apply is used to calculate 2 positions in the string, where the first number is found, and where the first period is found (& note a period is added to ensure this is always positive). From these positions the first number is isolated and then concatenated to '0000' eg. 6 becomes 00006 or 91 becomes 000091, then only the right 4 chars are used so we get 0001 .... 9999 possibilities.

*dbfiddle [demo here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=8d10de763708dfcf7b253bfa932669f3)*

Comment: the result is Q1                  
Q10                 
Q10.a               
Q10.b               
Q11                 
Q11.a               
Q12                 
Q12.a               
Q12.b     etc......

Comment: as I mentioned, the first line would not solve for numbers >= 10. The additional code will

Comment: not possible look at, http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=99b2f60c3f05fe7691651240660b65e5 you haven't done somethng I proposed above. run the full query I proposed above

Comment: @Sami, no I did not, if there are additional sequences that run above 10 then they too will need isolation

Comment: the type filed is nchar(20), start in Q2.a = 0002, Q2.b = 0002, etc...  Then Q1, Q2, etc is empty

Comment: Ah, ok, I will amend for that (I had assumed variable length strings) `select PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',rtrim(numbering)), PATINDEX('%[.]%',rtrim(numbering)+'.')`
`

Comment: Its works, Thanks @Used_By_Already


`select numbering , right('0000'+substring(numbering,pos1,pos2-pos1),4), pos1, pos2, substring(numbering,pos1,pos2-pos1)
from QuestionnaireQuestion
cross apply (
   select PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',rtrim(numbering)), PATINDEX('%[.]%',rtrim(numbering)+'.')
   ) ca (pos1, pos2) 
order by right('0000'+substring(numbering,pos1,pos2-pos1),4), numbering`

Comment: Great, but these numbering systems are awful. You would be better off by dividing those into pieces, which you could do as computed columns (persisted) . By the way: not sure why you use NCHAR(20) for this either, fixed length is such a waste of storage space.

Comment: I am not the database administrator and I also asked me the same questions, the same for the enumeration, but I will consider it when starting a project from scratch, thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

The real challenge here is that your are storing multiple pieces of information in a single tuple. This violates 1NF and is truly awful to work with. Since you have a varying number of elements this is even more difficult. Assuming you never exceed 3 elements you can use some ugly string manipulation as a hack to make this work. Please note the performance of this is not going to scale well but that is because the design is less than optimal.

```
declare @Something table (SomeValue varchar(20))

insert @Something (SomeValue) values
('Q2')
, ('Q2.a')
, ('Q2.b')
, ('Q3')
, ('Q4')
, ('Q4.a')
, ('Q5')
, ('Q6')
, ('Q6.a')
, ('Q6.a.1')
, ('Q6.a.2')
, ('Q6.a.3')
, ('Q6.a.4')
, ('Q7')
, ('Q8')
, ('Q8.a')
, ('Q9')
, ('Q10')
, ('Q10.a')
, ('Q10.b')
, ('Q11')
, ('Q11.a')
, ('Q12')
, ('Q12.a')
, ('Q12.b')
, ('Q13')
, ('Q13.a')
, ('Q13.a.1')
, ('Q13.a.2')
, ('Q13.a.3')
, ('Q13.a.4')
, ('Q13.a.5')
, ('Q13.a.6')
, ('Q13.a.7')
, ('Q13.a.8')
, ('Q13.b')
, ('Q13.b.1')
, ('Q13.b.2')
, ('Q13.b.3')
, ('Q13.b.4')
, ('Q13.b.5')
, ('Q13.b.6')
, ('Q13.b.7')
, ('Q13.b.8')
, ('Q1')
, ('Q11')


select *

from @Something s
order by reverse(PARSENAME(reverse(s.SomeValue), 1))
    , reverse(PARSENAME(reverse(s.SomeValue), 2))
    , reverse(PARSENAME(reverse(s.SomeValue), 3))
    --If you have 4 elements you can add one more level. 
    --But this will not work if you exceed 4 elements because of how PARSENAME works.
    --, reverse(PARSENAME(reverse(s.SomeValue), 4))
```